# ASP.Net Page with iFrame - X-Frame-Options

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to host a webpage (web app in an IFRAME).
Like this:

```
<iframe src="http://52.224......." 
    runat="server" id="IFrameX" name="IFrameX"
    style="position: absolute; height: 90%; border: none" />
```

I have added the following to the Web.Config

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOWALL"/>
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

When I run. I get the following errors:

> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading
>   'http://localhost:44379/index.html': 'ALLOW-FROM http://52.22...' is
>   not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
>
> Refused to display 'http://52.224...' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Any ideas?  I have also tried

```
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="allow-from http://52.224....."/>
```

thx!

Comment: Just checking you are changing the web.config for the page contained **within** the iframe?

Comment: No , it's in the solution containing the Default.aspx that contains the iFrame code

Comment: No , it's in the solution containing the Default.aspx that contains the iFrame code

Comment: `Refused to display 'http://52.224...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` is coming from the page you are inserting **into** the iframe. If you control that page, you need to change the header there. You can verify this by using the network tab in the Browser Tools in the browser of your choice and inspecting the response headers. More and more sites are setting that in the header these days, Google is just one prominent example.